# How to set python version to 2.7 for Yocto project work in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, yocto

I am new to the Yocto project on Ubuntu. It requires that python version 2.7 and not 3.X be used. I need to set the default version of Python to 2.7. How do I do this?

Comment: I would have bet money that "python" defaults to python2.7 on Ubuntu. Are you sure this is your problem?

Comment: Nope, it has both installed but when I try to run the yocto install script yocto complains that it needs 2.7. update-alternatives doesn';t seem to work either.

Comment: Can you document the script you are running and the yocto/poky version?

Comment: poky-rocko-18.0.2

Comment: oe-init-build-env

Comment: ...and I appreciate your help

Comment: np. So the setup script has found that "python" on your system for some reason does not point to python2.7. I'm fairly sure normally on Ubuntu it does so maybe you've changed something. `ls -l $(which python)` might give some clues

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 johann johann 9 Aug  8  2017 /home/johann/anaconda3/bin/python -> python3.6

Comment: johann@mars:~/yocto/poky-rocko-18.0.2$ source oe-init-build-env 
OpenEmbedded requires 'python' to be python v2 (>= 2.7.3), not python v3.
Please set up python v2 as your default 'python' interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

write on your Terminal

```
cd /usr/src
```

then Install Python from python.org

```
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tgz
```

then Unzip The tgz file by writing

```
sudo tar xzf Python-2.7.14.tgz
```

then Goto The Directory Python-2.7.14

```
cd Python-2.7.14
```

then Configure The Language

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

then add Python to your Path

```
sudo make altinstall
```

And Done Python 2.7.14(True version and original) installed

Comment: This does not answer the question "how to set 2.7 as default python" as far as I can see

Comment: All that was done... and I still get 

johann@mars:/usr/src/Python-2.7.14$ python -V
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18 installed and it has python 3 installed... I want to run Yocto project  and it explicitly needs  2.7 python.. I tried the update-alternatives and it does seem to change it either...